# Name 'from tr' soe not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a table with a 'tr' inside that's hidden. In the backend I want to show it after a click on a button, but somehow I can't get the tr by it's id-name. i'm working in ASP.net and with C#.

```
<table id="cost_tbl" runat="server" border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Rights</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="rol_1" runat="server"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="rol_2" runat="server"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="rol_3" runat="server"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="rol_totaal" runat="server"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="extra_cost1" runat="server" visible="false">
    <td>test</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="1" runat="server" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="2" runat="server" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="3" runat="server" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="4" runat="server" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So now I want to set the visibility of the 'tr' with id "extra_cost1" to true, with the code underneath but it fails and says:"the name 'extra_cost1' does not exist in the current context"

```
public void BtnAddCost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    extra_cost1.Visible = true;

}
```

Comment: Do other IDs work, e.g. `cost_tbl`? It's been a while since I used web forms, but perhaps you need `<asp:Table>`, `<asp:TableRow>` etc?

Comment: No, doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm not sure which question that was an answer to. Have you tried the `<asp:Table>` and `<asp:TableRow>` tags instead?

Comment: Both doesn't work, still gives the same error in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

[Page.FindControl Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Table, TableRow, and TableCell Web Server Control Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0ce8sc.aspx)

This is assuming that your table is not nested inside another control:

```
public void BtnAddCost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TableRow extra_cost1 = Page.FindControl("extra_cost1") as TableRow;
    extra_cost1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use `as` instead of a straight cast (i.e. `(TableRow)Page.FindControl("extra_cost1")`) you should check for `null` before using the variable. Otherwise you end up with a `NullReferenceException` instead of the more informative `InvalidCastException`.